# is free base an open source

Tags: freebase

is free base an open source api can i use it in any commercial application....

Comment: The terms of service are on their website; if you need further clarification contact their sales team http://www.freebase.com/policies/tos

Answer (score 4):

It looks like FreeBase is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution License which can be found here http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/.  Basically it says you are free to use it as long as you attribute the source of the data.  You are also bound by their ToS located here, http://www.freebase.com/policies/tos.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the license information for [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com):

http://www.freebase.com/policies/index/